# Tool to give an overview of PowerPoint contents

Tags: powerpoint

I'm looking for at simple tool that will give a hierarchical overview of the elements of a PowerPoint file; in particular, showing the sizes of images, videos etc. and where they are placed in the file. Does such a tool exist?

I know that simply renaming a PowerPoint file to .zip (if necessary, saving as strict OpenXML first) and unzipping will give me the images etc., but I'm looking for a simple tool that will display the information about the elements without going through this process.